# Airplay connections notification and status bar airplay icon

Tags: ios, swift, airplay

As per the airplay usage is given in :
https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204289#iOS

[image]

The app supports the airplay but I can't see this icon. Need to understand from development perspective how do we enable to show airplay icon when it is connected to airplay

Answer (score 0):

Add LongFormVideo for the audio session policy:

[image: LongFormVideo]

Apple suggested that the content that includes things such as movies or the TV type content like TV shows, sports etc comes in long-form video category.
And if your app primarily plays content from social media or other types of short news clips, then it would not qualify as long-form video.

For more details, this wwdc session is very useful to understand the airplay options presented as per Apple Guidelines:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/501/